# How much time can a human withstand without breathing? (after expelling all the air from the lungs)

Tags: lungs

How much time (how many seconds) can a human withstand without breathing? (after expelling all the air from the lungs)?

Any paper?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: There is such a thing as competitive breath holding, so records are readily available on this. Look up static apnea.